# past participle vs past simple

Tags: grammar, past-simple, past-participles

I am having massive difficulty in trying to decipher if the following sentence whether is a past participle in the passive voice or past simple in the passive voice?

> The woman was robbed yesterday.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? How would the sentence look like if it was written in the other tense? What does a grammar book say?

Comment: _Was_ is a finite verb. English does not usually allow two finite verbs in the same clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think learners have a lot of **unnecessary** difficulty with participles.

A participle can act as part of verb, as an adjective, or (if a present participle) a noun (frequently called a gerund).

So your question is based on a false premise.

"Was robbed" is a phrasal verb in the past tense, passive voice, because passive voice is always formed with what I prefer to call the passive-perfect participle and some form of the verb "be."

"Robbed" does not cease being a participle because it is part of a verb.

If you think about participles as having multiple uses instead of the use determining whether or not it is a participle, you will avoid a lot of unnecessary mental anguish.

P.S. It is sometimes hard to decide whether it is best to describe a participle as being used as part of a verb or as an adjective. Don't worry about it; it makes no difference to the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly are confused.

The passive voice is formed from the past participle.  It is (Be verb) + (past participle)

The (be verb) here is "was".  And that is in the past tense.

So this is past tense, "was".

And "robbed" is a past participle.

And together this is the past tense of the passive voice.

(There is an alternative, "robbed" might be an adjective.  It's probably not, because it can't be graded: you can't be "very robbed". Moreover you could insert "by a thief" that points to this being a participle and the passive voice, not an adjective)

Comment: Another great answer that I shall upvote.  The point about “grading” of adjectives is quite subtle.

Answer (score 0):

As Colin Fine said, "was" is the main verb, so "was robbed" is the **simple past tense**. Specifically, the "*robbed*" in "was robbed" is a *past participle*, not a past simple. In this case the "robbed" past participle was used as an adjective.

My advice for someone learning English is to identify all words that *could* be verbs. The relative location of the possible verbs can help with identifying their tense.

Typically, "was + [verb]" or any other "[to-be] + [verb]" implies a different form of verbs. My suggestion is to **look out specifically for [to-be] verbs** (is, are, was, were, etc.) to help with identifying the tenses of other verbs.

One helpful table would be "The Full List of Tenses" in https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/tense.htm.

Source: https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm

EDIT: changed "past progressive tense" (was robbing) to "simple past tense". Thanks 3kstc!

Comment: Jay, past progressive would be: _she **was robbing**  the bank._

Comment: @3kstc Thanks! That was entirely my bad, I just saw the "was" and jumped the gun. I corrected it in my post